# Get a table from url1.html into url2.html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, import

I need to display a table from url1.html into an other webpage url2.html :

```
<body>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<div><a id="insertion" style="display:none" w3-include-html="url1.html"></a></div>
<div id = 'todisplay'></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript"> w3IncludeHTML();                  
var table = document.getElementById('insertion');
var newtable = table.getElementsByTagName('table')[1];
document.getElementById("todisplay").appendChild(newtable);
</script>
```

The javaScript works fine when I use chrome or IE developping tools.
Furthermore, I do not want to use a `<link rel=import ...>` stuff because of CORS.

Thanks in advance,

Konok

Comment: I can't see the link bet ween cors and html imports

Comment: You cannot "store" a HTML page into a <link rel="import"> unless url1.html and url2.html are within the same domain (because of CORS). Which is not my case. So I do not want to use this method. :)